# Dynamic view date localisation xpage

Tags: localization, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I am using Dynamic view with localisationsetter bean given below and works well on normal views.

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xpages-localization-setter

I see that locaisation isn't working on Dynamic views. Any ideas would be very much helpful.

Comment: Can you verify if the phaselistener is being executed or not when switching with the dynamic view control?